# AWK - Show lines where column contains a specific string

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk

I have a document (.txt) composed like that.

```
info1: info2: info3: info4
```

And I want to show some information by column.
For example, I have some different information in "info3" shield, I want to see only the lines who are composed by "test" in "info3" column.

I think I have to use sort but I'm not sure.
Any idea ?

Comment: So you have a bunch of colon separated values, and you want to see only the lines that have 'test' in the third column?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want!

Comment: Providing an actual input file with sample data would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this.  Assuming your columns are de-limited by `:` and column 3 has entries having `test`, below command lists only those lines having that value.

```
awk -F':' '$3=="test"' input-file
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are assuming that the third column is exactly equal to `test`. It looks like you were looking for columns where the value *included test*. We need to use awk's `match` function

```
awk -F: 'match($3, "test")' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the spacing is consistent, and you're looking for only `test` in the third column, use

```
grep ".*:.*: test:.*" file.txt
```

Or to take care of any spacing that might occur

```
grep ".*:.*: *test *:.*" file.txt
```

Comment: Ok, so "sort" is useless in this case?
Thanks for your help, but I used "sort –k3n,3n ", this is bad so?

Comment: If that does what I think you're trying to do, it just sorts it by the third column. Which may be what you want, but won't just give you lines with `test` there.

Comment: Ok it's work pretty well but grep works too if I want to exclude an information ?
For example, if I want to show all the line who are not composed by "test" in the 3rd column?
I think it's the same processus but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use `grep -v ...` to show only things that don't match.

Comment: Maybe my question was bad formulated.
For example I have :
info1: info2: test1: info4
info1: info2: test2: info4
info1: info2: test1: info4

I want to show all lines who are not "test2".

Comment: Does that not work? `grep -v ".*:.*: *test2 *:.*" file.txt`

Comment: Oh sorry, bad manipulation, this command work ! Thank you so much

Comment: Everything works good.
And if I want to see "test2" who is in the first line of the document, what I should do ?
I think I have to take just the 1st line of my document and after take the 3rd column?

For example :
info1: info2: info3: info4
info5: info6: info7: info8
info9: info10: info11: info12

I just want the "Info3" information in one request.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what? You mean you want to check if `test2` appears in the first line of the document in the third column?

Comment: I want to show only test2 who is in 3rd column, first line of the document.

Comment: If you mean you only want to see the first line... `head -1 file.txt | grep ".*:.*: *test2 *:.*"`

Comment: That's what I wanted, thanks.
I was not sure how to use head and grep in one command but now I understand. Thanks